# Patch stack tools for Windows

Tags: windows, linux, patch

Are there any equivalents in the Windows world for patch stack management tools like Linux's quilt?  I'm trying to come up with some development workflows for our environment, which need to work on both Linux and Windows.  I can come up with a beautiful system for Linux using quilt and the like, but unless I can find a way to replicate it on Windows as well (including pretty GUI's for all the command-line-phobic developers), I'm basically stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Mercurial's [Queues](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/MqExtension) can help? I do believe they work in the Windows implementation of Mercurial, too.

Answer (score 1):

I use quilt on Windows by way of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).